# Unable to launch flow from apex with record collection input

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I am attempting to launch a flow using the `Invocable.Action` class, passing in a collection of cases to be processed but am unable to with the following error:

`System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Test_Case_Assignment: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION - The input parameter "records" can't accept values of type SObjectList.: []`

Here's a snippet of how I'm attempting to launch the flow. I tried casting the newList to cases with no luck.

```
  public void launchFlow(List<SObject> newList) {
    List<Case> cases = (List<Case>) newList;
    List<Map<String, Object>> inputs = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
    inputs.add(new Map<String, Object>{ 'records' => cases });
    Invocable.Action action = Invocable.Action.createCustomAction(
      'Flow',
      'Test_Case_Assignment'
    );
    action.setInvocations(inputs);
    List<Invocable.Action.Result> results = action.invoke();
  }
```

It appears this is a bug or lack of feature with the `Invocable.Action` class as I can launch a similar flow with just a single record at a time.

[image: Screenshot of input variable]

Comment: Is the input variable set as a collection?

Comment: yes, it's a collection of records of type case. Added a screenshot

Comment: you need to change your invocable method signature to `List<List<SObject>>`

Comment: @cropredy could you expand on that? I tried updating cases to a list of lists of cases and passing that into inputs but I got the error `The input parameter "records" can't accept values of type ScalarList.: []`

Answer (score 0):

An invocable action is always bulkified - even when interacting with screen flows

In a transaction, each affected record gets its own Flow Interview. These run logically in parallel

When the records hit the Apex Action in the flow, the interview waits until all of the other interviews hit the apex action. Then, the Flow engine assembles each of the interview's arguments to the invocable action into a single collection

Thus, if the invocable is supposed to accept a collection from a single Interview, the signature of the invocable is a `List<List<someObject>> requests`

- Interview One passes a collection of Cases 1 and 3
- Interview Two passes a collection of Cases 2 and 6
- Interview Three passes a collection of just Case 9

The invocable sees this a list of lists (logically, like this):

```
[
  [1,3],
  [2,4],
  [9]
]
```

If the invocable returns anything, it must be also a List where list element 0 in the return corresponds to the input list element 0 and so on

Comment: I wasn't able to get this method working. I tried assigning 'records' to a list of list of cases instead of just a list of cases.
It resulted in the following error message `UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION - The input parameter "records" can't accept values of type ScalarList.: []`
The way I understand it is that the invocable takes a list of mappings where each invocation is one of those mappings.

Comment: each flow should assign its record collection to the collection variable exposed by the invocable apex.  the Flow engine then bulkifies all the interviews and presents to the invocable a list of lists. A given Flow Interview never worries about what the other interviews are doing

Comment: were you able to get this working and are sharing what worked or is this just a suggestion?

Comment: without seeing how you defined the input variable of your flow, my answer is more of a "guide"